# VBA to copy and SUM the data then paste it into NEWSHEET

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have created this code which copy and paste the data after matching the particular value from Row 6 then paste the Row 7 data in NewSheet.

I am unable to create that thing in Excel VBA. IF there are multiple "Gross Wage" in the "Sheet1" then how code will SUM the "Gross Wage" from multiple rows and paste that "SUM" data into "NEWSHEET".

Let me share an example.
[image]

Looking to create a code which will automatically SUM that "Gross Wage" rows and paste that SUM data into "NEWSHEET"

your help will be highly appreciated.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
 Set c = .Rows(6).Find("Q1 2020")
 If Not c Is Nothing Then
.Range(c.Offset(1), c.Offset(1).End(xlToRight)).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NewSheet").Cells(10, 11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
 End If
 End With
```

Final Result
[image]

Comment: @FaneDuru thank you for looking at this issue, Let me explain that. right now there are 5 "GrossWage" in Col"C" that wages can be increase or decrease. I just want that if there are 5 "GrossWage" in "Sheet2" code will find that how many "GrossWage" are available in Col"C" after that code will SUM that wages (as i did in row 25 for just an example). after that code will paste that SUM data in "NewSheet" RangeF10

Comment: So, the Sum formula does not exist and must be calculated for each existing columns, starting from the `c` one. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes exactly it is correct.

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer. But, in order to avoid misunderstandings, there are not any row summarizing the column values...

Comment: Yes there is no row summarizing the column value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the next code, please:

```
Sub testCopySumQ()
 Dim sh2 As Worksheet, shNS As Worksheet, c As Range
 Dim lastR As Long, lastCol As Long, arrS, strForm As String
 
 Set sh2 = ActiveSheet 'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
 Set shNS = sh2.Next 'Worksheets("NewSheet")
 With sh2
     Set c = .rows(6).Find("Q1 2020")
     If Not c Is Nothing Then
        lastR = .cells(rows.count, c.Column).End(xlUp).row 'last row on the c Column
        lastCol = .cells(c.row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last col (even with gaps)
        strForm = "=SumIf(" & c.Offset(1, -5).Address & ":" & .cells(lastR, c.Column - 5).Address & _
            ", ""Gross Wage"", " & c.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & ":" & .cells(lastR, c.Column).Address(0, 0) & ")"
                                                  
        .cells(lastR + 1, c.Column).Formula = strForm  'place the SumIf formula on last empty column cell
        .cells(lastR + 1, c.Column).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.cells(lastR + 1, c.Column), _
                                            .cells(lastR + 1, lastCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault 'fill the formula to right
        With .Range(.cells(lastR + 1, c.Column), .cells(lastR + 1, lastCol))
            arrS = .Value   'put the value in an array
            .ClearContents  'clear the helper row
        End With
        'drop the array value
        shNS.cells(10, 11).Resize(UBound(arrS), UBound(arrS, 2)).Value = arrS
     End If
 End With
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

But do you really need to always paste in "K10" cell? Or in the last empty cell of "K:K" column? Just in case of inserting other columns between this column and the one keeping the quarter string.

**Edited**:

I used for the column where "Gross Wage" string exists `Offset(1, -5)`, meaning to be on the fifth column before the column where "Q1 2020" will be found...

Comment: FaneDuru, Thank you so much its working great. but there is one issue if i add one more row with different header it also calculates it it should not SUM the "Row23" which header is "Nothing" the code will always count "Gross Wage" please see attached picture https://ibb.co/qxdy7bc

Comment: I will change the cell reference "K10" if needed.

Comment: @Learning: So, your real situation does not look like the one in your question picture... You should mention that some other rows may interfere. But let us clarify the issue: Do you need to be summarized only the values on the rows having on column C:C the string "Gross Wage". Is that correct? This will bother a little the formulas, but if this is your need, even not expressed in your question, I can do it. But I do not like Sisyphus work... I will do it only if you confirm/state it. :)

Comment: I do apologies that i did not mentioned it in my question @FaneDuru  if its possible then please create it. I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: OK. I will do it, but it is a little more complicated. I will use `SumIf` formula with absolute reference to C:C column and relative to the other one...

Comment: @Learning: Please, test the updated code (formula, in fact) and confirm that it works as you need.

Comment: @Learning: Glad I could help!. But take care of an eventual column insert between C:C column and the one keeping the quarter string. If you need C:C to remain forever, the formula can be changed in this regards. If you need to insert other columns (in the future), it is good to do that before C:C, or to update the code, transforming -5 in -6, -7 and so on, for each column inserted in between...

Comment: Thank you so much for suggesting it i got you point.